# Verification of proof on repeated root for a quadratic polynomial

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, formal-proofs

I'm fairly new to writing proofs so I'd appreciate it if anyone could point out amy holes in this proof, and if there's any comments so I could improve my proof writing!

Question: 
"Let $a ≠ 0$. If there exists one $x_1$ such that $ax_1^2 + bx_1 + c = 0$ and no other. Without using the quadratic formula, show that $b^2 - 4ac = 0$."

I'm also given the proposition that if $a ≠ 0$,  $ax_1^2 + bx_1 + c = 0$ and $ax_2^2 + bx_2 + c = 0$ then $x_2 = -(\frac{b}{a} + x_1)$.

If it's given that only one such $x_1$ exists for the first equation, I assume I may let $x_2 = x_1$, so then I end up with $x_1 = -(\frac{b}{2a})$. Then, by substituting into the first equation, I arrive at

$a(\frac{b^2}{4a^2}) - b(\frac{b}{2a}) + c = 0$

We have $a ≠ 0$, so simplifying we get

$\frac{-(b^2 - 4ac)}{4a} = 0$

Implying $b^2 - 4ac$ is equal to zero.

Comment: Your proof looks fine. However, I think it's simpler & more direct to use the [Quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) instead.

Comment: I don't think you should say "since $a\ne0$" in the last line

Comment: @JohnOmielan Ah, sorry about that, seems like I forgot to include that I wasn't allowed to use the quadratic formula in the original question.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I assume i should omit any details that were already given before in the proof?

Comment: It certainly matters that $a\neq 0$ because the fractional expression would not have a clear meaning otherwise.  But $a=0$ would not provide an alternative explanation  (to the numerator being zero) for the fraction being zero.  Your phrasing currently suggests that it must be one or the other.

Comment: There’s a typo.  It should say $ x_1+x_2= -b/a $

Comment: @hardmath So in this case for better phrasing, I should leave the 'since $a ≠ 0$' out then?

Comment: @dm63 I don't believe that's a typo, since $x_2 + x_1 = 2x_1$ which leads to my last expression for $x_1$, unless you're suggesting I should add a bit more steps to my proof?

Comment: It makes sense to mention $a\neq 0$ when you first divide by $a$.

Comment: @hardmath I see, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Thanks i must have misread it earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ax^2 +bx +c =a(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x )+c =$$

$$a(x+\frac {b}{2a})^2 +c -\frac {b^2}{4a} = a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2 -\frac {b^2-4ac}{4a} $$ in order for the equation to have double root we need $$\frac {b^2-4ac}{4a}=0 $$